# How to write .indexOn for Nested values in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[image]

I have wrote on below rules for Get the value form chats with key createdAt But i cant able to get the values from Firebase DB. Rules are Below

```
"chats": {
  ".read" : true,
  ".write" : "auth !== null",
      "messages" : {
            ".indexOn": ["userName", "createdAt", "userId"]
        }
},
```

chats/messages.json?orderBy="createdAt"&startAt=1485920224250&print=pretty

Comment: Could you please edit your original post to clarify what your question is? Your title says you want to write a rule to index nested values in Firebase, but later in your post you say you can't get values. Something else is wrong if you are not returning data from Firebase.

Comment: I have write the rules for chats/messages.json?orderBy="createdAt"&startAt=1485920224250&print=pretty, but firebase doesnt return anything, kindly advice me what rules need to add in firebase

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a level in your rules:

```
"chats": {
  ".read" : true,
  ".write" : "auth !== null",
  "$chatId": {
      "messages" : {
            ".indexOn": ["userName", "createdAt", "userId"]
        }
  }
},
```

Comment: I Have tried your solution but it throw some error  {
  "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"createdAt\", for path \"/chats/messages\", to the rules"
}

Comment: Yeah, I see now that you're trying to get chat rooms based on the timestamp of the messages in them. That won't work. If you want to get the chat rooms in the order of when they were last updates, you must have a property on the chat room that indicates when it was last updated.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, but what about indexing both chats AND messages?